# Creating Exception in Excel Sum to Avoid error Value

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

this is the formula:
`=DATE(YEAR(Q14),MONTH(Q14),DAY(Q14)+(R14))`

I'm using to add date how do I make exception that it keep the answer blank until I enter the date in Q column

Answer (score 0):

You could use the
[IF function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/if-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2).

This is my untested formulation :

```
=IF(ISBLANK(Q14),"",DATE(YEAR(Q14),MONTH(Q14),DAY(Q14)+(R14)))
```